# How to get on server side html element attribute?

Tags: java, servlets

I have this code:

```
out.println("<form action=\"srvSearchResults\" method=\"post\">");
out.println("<tr>");
Book b = freeBooks.get(i);
out.println("<td><input type='submit' data-isbn=\""+b.getIsbn()+"\" name=\"ddd\" value=\""+b.getTitle()+"\" style=\"padding:0; border:none; background:none; cursor:pointer\" ></td>");
out.println("<td>" + b.getIsbn() + "</td>");
out.println("<td>" + b.getAuthorName() + "</td>");
out.println("<td>" + b.getPublishDate() + "</td>");
out.println("<td>" + "Free to borrow!" + "</td>");
out.println("</tr>");
out.println("</form>");
```

When I click on submit in generated code the servlet function is fired and by this row:

```
String isbn = request.getParameter("ddd");
```

I try to get value of  `data-isbn` but it's  null.

Any idea how can I get data-isbn attribute on server side afer submit?

Comment: Would you mind check which parameters are sent on the submit action?

Answer (score 1):

When you submit an HTML form, only the values of the form fields are sent to the server, not all of the attributes. So the way it is written now, there is no way to get the value, because your server never received it.

If you want to get your ISBN, you can add an additional hidden input field that contains it:

```
out.println("<input type='hidden' name='isbn' value='" + b.getIsbn() + "'>");
```

You can put this right after the `<form>` open tag.

If you submit your form you can then use

```
String isbn = request.getParameter("isbn");
```

to get the ISBN.

As a side note: `<form>` is an invalid parent for [`<tr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) elements. Therefor it is possible that the form doesn't behave the way you intend it to.